# Как изменить regedit windows с помощью c++?

Tags: c++

Например нужно поменять уже существующее значение на другое , как я могу это сделать?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions

Comment: читал , все равно особо не понял

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D